# Vector coefficients based on similarity

Tags: machine-learning, vector, similarity, recommendation-engine

I've been looking for a solution to create a recommendation system based on vectors similarity.
Basically, i have a few vectors per user for example:

```
User1: [0,3,7,8,5] , [3,5,8,2,4] , [1,5,3,9,4]
User2: [3,1,6,7,9] , [2,4,1,3,8] , [7,8,3,3,1]
```

For every vector i need to calculate a coefficient and based on that coefficient differentiate a vector from another. I've found formulas that would calculate coefficients based on similarity of 2 vectors which i don't really want that.I need a formula that would calculate a coefficient per vector and then i do some other calculations with those coefficients.Are there any good formulas for this?
Thanks

Comment: To clarify: you've found vector similarity measures which for given vectors `A` and `B` tell you how similar `A` is to `B`, but you want a single measure, calculated on a per-vector basis, which can tell you for vectors `A`, `B`, and `C`, how similar `A` is to `B`, and also how similar `A` is to `C`, etc?

Comment: Yes that's what i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So going based off your response to my comment: I don't think there's a similarity coefficient measure that will do what you want. Let me explain why...

Similarity coefficients are functions `f(x, y) -> c` where `x` and `y` are vectors and `c` is a scalar. Note that `f` takes two parameters. `f(x,y) = f(y,x)`, but `f(x)` is meaningless - its asking for the similarity of `x` relative to... nothing.

So what? We could just use a function `g(x) = f(x, V)` where `V` is a fixed vector. E.g. let `V = [1, 1, ..., 1]`. Now we have a monadic function that gives us a similarity value for every individual vector. But...

Knowing `f(x,y) = c` and `f(x,z) = c'` doesn't tell you a whole lot about `f(y,z)`. Take vectors in 2-space, `x = [1, 1], y = [0, 1], z = [1,0]`. A similarity function symmetric in the two dimensions would say `f(x,y) = f(x,z)` but hopefully not `= f(y,z)` So our `g` function above isn't very useful, because knowing how similar two vectors are to `V` doesn't tell us much about how similar they are to each other.

---

So what can you do? I think a simple solution to your problem would be a variation of the [k nearest neighbors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm%22k%20nearest%20neighbors%22) algorithm. It allows you to find vectors close to a given vector (or, if you prefer to find clusters of vectors without specifying a given vector, look up [clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis))

EDIT: inspiration from Yahya's answer: if your vectors are super huge and knn or clustering is too difficult, consider principle component analysis or some other method of cutting them down to size (reducing the number of dimensions) - just keep in mind whatever you do will likely be lossy